# How do i install dual boot on Computer from USB stick?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, usb, lubuntu, windows-8

as the question says... 
My disc drive is broken and wont open at all so i want install/dual boot Windows8 and Ubuntu 14.04 from USB stick , how do i acomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As a starter you can use the program "Unetbootin" to create a bootable installation media on USB of Ubuntu. See: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/
For the Dual Boot somebody else has to help.. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Actually merely plugging in a USB memory stick or USB external hard drive permits you to use the usual Install Ubuntu options you would have with an external hard drive.  The catch is that if you do this while a pre-existing installation of windows is also mounted, the boot sector of that other drive will be altered such that the computer will not be bootable again unless the USB drive is connected to the computer.

In my personal experience with Unetbootin, while it is very useful, I have never seen it render a bootable memory stick which you would save files to the way one would with regular internal installations.